# Continuous projections on $\ell_1$ with norm $>1$

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I was trying to find papers and articles about non-contractive continuous projections on $\ell_1(S)$ where $S$ is an arbitrary set. If it is not studied yet, I would like to know results for the case $S=\mathbb{N}$.

I've found one quite general condition for the closed linear subspace to be image of a continuous projection. Such a subspace must be the closure of the linear span of so-called relatively disjoint vectors. This subspaces gives us explicit examples of projections with norm greater than 1. For details see the paper of H. P. Rosenthal [On relatively disjoint families of measures, with some applications to Banach space theory](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm37/sm3712.pdf).

As a special case we can get subspaces that are the closure of the linear span of disjointly supported vectors. These subspaces give us examples of norm one projections. Moreover, only such subspaces are give rise to norm one projections. For details see the survey by Beata Randrianantoanina [Norm one projections in Banach spaces](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110171v1.pdf).

Thus, for projections of norm 1 we have a complete description. For the rest quite a big source of examples. In the first mentioned paper the author states that he doesn't know any other examples of continuous projections on $\ell_1(S)$ that are not generated by some relatively disjoint family of vectors.

So, could someone give me a reference where I can read about other examples of projections on $\ell_1(S)$, or may be their complete characterization?

Also I will be grateful if you give me some explicit examples of discontinuous projections on $\ell_1(S)$.

The [same question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101139/continuous-projections-in-ell-1-with-norm-1) on mathoverflow.net.

Comment: If you put a 500 bounty on this its chances of getting answered will sky rocket.

Comment: Are you interested in (1) subspaces which don't admit continuous projections [namely, uncomplemented subspaces], or (2) in discontinuous projections themselves? The examples of (2) can be constructed even in a Hilbert space, where all subspaces are complemented.

Comment: I'm interested in quite explicit description of non-contractive projections. I've will have it, of course, I'll get examples of discontinuous projections. Examples of uncomplemented subspaces will be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks @JonasMeyer, I wanted to put this bounty in the end of the summer, but you are the first. If someone answer it (the way I wanted) I'll put another 500 bounty for him/her.

Comment: Here's an idea (which I leave as a comment rather than an answer since I have not checked enough of the details). Take a subspace $E$ of $\ell^1$ that is isomorphic with small Banach-Mazur constant to $\ell^2$. (You can probably get something out of Khintchine's inequality.) Take a large finite-dimensional subspace of $E$, call it $F$. Then any projection of $\ell^1$ onto $F^\perp$ should have large norm, since otherwise by taking $F$ larger and larger we could eventually build a projection of $\ell^1$ onto $E^\perp$ and hence onto $E$, which is impossible.

Comment: @Yemon: I don't understand your comment. There is no subspace of $\ell^1$ isomorphic to $\ell^2$ by Pitt's theorem. A closed infinite-dimensional subspace of $\ell^p$ cannot be isomorphic to a closed subspace of $\ell^q$ if $1 \leq p \neq q \lt \infty$ since the operator in one direction would have to be compact.

Comment: @Norbert: Do you search for a construction of a discontinuous projection in $\ell_1(S)$, without using the axiom of choice ?

Comment: @francis-jamet, no I haven't searched for that. So all examples that you know based on axiom of choice?

Comment: Yes, an example: if $F$ is a complement of the subspace of finite sequences, and $f_{|F} \mapsto 0$ and $f(e_n)=ne_1$. Sorry if it doesn't help.

Comment: What is $f$? Is this minimal projection on $\mathrm{span}\{e_1\}$?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is a projection on span $\{e_1\}$.

Comment: @francis-jamet: It's impossible to prove that there is a discontinuous linear map without invoking some strong form of choice -- "you can't write down a discontinuous linear map defined on all of a Banach space". For instance, it follows from the [axiom of determinacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) that every linear map on a separable Banach space is continuous.

Comment: @t.b. Oops, you are quite right, I was trying to use the Rademachers inside $L^1$ and then transport by finite-dimensional representability. However, one can still find copies of fin-dim $\ell^2$ inside $\ell^1$ (Dvoretzky, but I think Khintchine should work) and then take projections onto complements of these fin-dim subspaces

Comment: @t.b. Very interesting, thanks.

Comment: If Bill Johnson did not say anything informative at mathoverflow, it is hopeless to expect an answer here, at MSE.

Comment: Every Banach space which is not isometric to a Hilbert space contains a two-dimensional subspace which is not 1-complemented. On the other hand, every 2-dimensional Banach space embeds isometrically into $\ell_1$ (Herz–Lindenstrauss), so I think that even at the level of two-dimensional subspaces the situation can be quite difficult. Maybe you should somehow narrow yourself and ask a more specific question?

Comment: @TomekKania, ok here is the question that bothers me for years: Let $T:\ell_1^0(M)\to X$ be a quotient map between normed spaces. For each $C>1$ we have a right inverse $S$ of $T$ of norm $<C$. Is it true that $X=\ell_1^0(N)$ for some $N$. If you can answer this question or give a counterexample I can organize it as separate MSE question and give the maximal bounty for it. Twice.

Comment: Sorry, what is $\ell_1^0(M)$?

Comment: @TomekKania, $c_{00}(M)$ - finitely supported sequences on $M$, $\ell_1^0(M)$ - $c_{00}(M)$ with $\ell_1$-norm. In a more fancy way my question is the following: Is it true that all projective (with respect to quotients maps) spaces in the category of normed spaces are $\ell_1^0(M)$.

Comment: This is a result of Helemskii http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.5750v1.pdf

Comment: @TomekKania, this paper handles projectivity with respect to restricted class of quotient maps (they map closed unit ball onto closed unita ball), and my question is about all quotient maps

Comment: @TomaszKania you can post [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128821/continuous-projections-on-ell-1-with-norm-1#comment1877321_128821) as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, regard $\ell^1(S)$ for $S=\{0,1\}$.

Let $e_0=(R,0)$ and $e_1=(R,r)$ for $R$ and $r$ both nonzero.

Then $\|e_0\|_1=R$ while $\|e_1-e_0\|_1=r$.

From this we obtain a projection $P:\ell^1(S)\to\ell^1(S)$ given by
$$P(e_0):=e_0\textrm{ and }P(e_1):=0,$$

whose norm is bounded from below by $R/r$.

In particular, for $R>r$ we obtain $\|P\|>1$.

Comment: I think the op was asking about general results instead of examples. But +1 for the nice construction.

Comment: @Vim: Oh yes, true that, missread the question. But thanks for the compliment. :) Do you think I should remove or leave the answer then?

Comment: perhaps you can leave it till the op sees it and decides whether it's helpful or not to the question? I don't know.